# VBA: Regex and Dir() function questions

Tags: regex, vba, excel, directory

I wrote a simple script, using VBA. (I need to optimize some work with excel).

First question about Regex:

As I said before, I used VBA.

Simple task: get a match of pattern and capture the submatches.

my code is:

```
Dim ResStr as Object
Dim LastStr as Object
Dim RE as Object


Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp") 'create a regex
With RE
    .MultiLine = False  'm-key
    .Global = False     'g-key
    .IgnoreCase = False 'i-key
    .Pattern = "[<]TD\s+class=gm[>](\d+\.\d+)[<][/]TD[>]" 'tag
End With

Set ResStr = RE.Execute(StrDollar)  'use regex  
Set LastStr = ResStr(0).SubMatches  'get submatch
```

How do I get the LAST match and LAST submatch? (length-property?)

Second question about Dir function:

How do I filter the files?

I saw this code on msdn:

```
   ' Display the names in C:\ that represent directories.
   MyPath = "c:\"   ' Set the path.
   MyName = Dir(MyPath, vbDirectory)   ' Retrieve the first entry.
   Do While MyName <> ""   ' Start the loop.
     ' Use bitwise comparison to make sure MyName is a directory.
     If (GetAttr(MyPath & MyName) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then
       ' Display entry only if it's a directory.
       Debug.WriteLine(MyName)
     End If   
     MyName = Dir()   ' Get next entry.
  Loop
```

`If (GetAttr(MyPath & MyName) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then` - stop 'msdn-guy'! are you kidding? is it ONLY one method?

Is there any possible way to make normal filter, not this tremendous-line method?

Comment: (1) Do you have a sample string for us to test to give you the last match? (2) You have two very separate questions here and they should be asked as such

Comment: <TD class=gm>20.20</TD><TD class=gm>22.22</TD>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get all matches, submatches, length etc you would use something like this - I have added a working example with a simpler pattern to demonstrate (ie match a sequences of numbers with then a non-number)

You should `Test` your regexp before presuming a match has been found to avoid erros

```
Sub Test()
Dim RE As Object
Dim strSample As String
Dim ResStr As Object
Dim LastStr As Object
strSample = "123dd6789a"
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")    'create a regex
With RE
    .MultiLine = False  'm-key
    .Global = True     'g-key
    .IgnoreCase = False    'i-key
    .Pattern = "\d+([^\d])"
End With
If RE.Test(strSample) Then
    Set ResStr = RE.Execute(strSample)
    For Each LastStr In ResStr
        MsgBox "Match: " & LastStr & vbNewLine & "SubMatch: " & LastStr.submatches(0) & vbNewLine & "Position: " & LastStr.firstindex + 1 & vbNewLine & "Length: " & LastStr.Length
    Next
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1**

You could try this:

```
Sub Test(StrDollar)
Dim LastStr As Object
Dim RE As New RegExp
Dim mt As Match


With RE
    .MultiLine = False  'm-key
    .Global = True     'g-key
    .IgnoreCase = False 'i-key
    .Pattern = "<TD\s+class=gm>(\d+\.\d+)</TD>" 'tag
    For Each mt In .Execute(StrDollar)
         Set LastStr = mt.SubMatches  'get submatch
    Next mt
End With

MsgBox LastStr(0)

End Sub
```

---

**Quetion 2**

Perhaps `dir()` function is not able to make a list of files based of a extension.

[EDIT]

```
Sub Test2(StrDollar)
Dim LastStr As Object
Dim RE As New RegExp
Dim mt As Match
Dim dic As New Scripting.Dictionary 'scripting runtime
Dim pos&

With RE
    .MultiLine = False  'm-key
    .Global = True     'g-key
    .IgnoreCase = False 'i-key
    .Pattern = "<TD\s+class=gm>(\d+\.\d+)</TD>" 'tag
    For Each mt In .Execute(StrDollar)
        pos = pos + 1
        dic.Add CStr(pos), mt.FirstIndex & "||" & mt.Value & "||" & mt.SubMatches(0)
    Next mt
End With

MsgBox dic.item(CStr(pos))

End Sub
```

[/EDIT]

Comment: great! but how about last submatch, if i have it? like this: `.Pattern="<TD\s+class=gm>(\d+)\.(\d+)</TD>"`. and how about indexation in both: matches and submatches?